Why does pnpm inconsistently display the list of deprecated subdependencies on install?
In one of the repos I use regularly, when running pnpm install (or pnpm install --resolution-only), it displays a warning about deprecated subdependencies, e.g.,
 WARN  6 deprecated subdependencies found:

However, in a different repo I also use, pnpm never displays that warning even though I'm sure it must also have deprecated subdependencies (e.g., some packages which have deprecated subdependencies are present in both repos but I only see the warning in one).
Is there any kind of configuration which could vary this pnpm behavior across repos?
I can't find any obvious pnpm configuration settings which would control whether this warning is generally displayed. I looked in the package.json and .npmrc file in both repos and nothing obviously seemed different across them as regards pnpm configuration. pnpm.allowDeprecatedVersions is not set anywhere. I'm using the same machine and same global version of pnpm in both cases.
Thanks!
